# How to show theoretical convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence

I was doing various tasks about convergence/divergence of series, where i had to use various theorems, but here i don't have any numbers, just general series.

So i have problem with two of them.

We know that $a_n$ is positive and $\sum a_n$ is convergent. Is that true $\sum a_n\sqrt[4]{a_n}$ converges too? Is it true that $\sum \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges too?

In first task i was trying to show that it diverges, but i couldn't find any series to get into comparison test. In second one i have no clue how to show it, because, to my intuition, if $a_n$ converges and $a_n$ has only positive numbers, then smaller number converges too.

Any help? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, hence $0\leqslant a_n\leqslant 1$ for $n$ large enough and $a_n\sqrt[4]{a_n}\leqslant a_n$.

We have $n^{-1/2}\leqslant 1$ for each $n$ hence we conclude similarly.

Comment: That's so easy and smart! thank you =)